# RMM subdomain query

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am configuring SFMC and have a subdomain for sends, my question is do I really need a seperate subdomain to manage RMM? Or can it be the same one? Am interesated in following best practice here
Thanks for any responses

Answer (score 0):

You can use RMM on the domain you send from, given there is an MX record configured, pointing at Salesforce. If there is an existing MX record pointing towards your own email servers (i.e. the subdomain is also used for other purposes which require you to receive emails) RMM will not be possible. If the subdomain is delegated entirely to Salesforce DNS - [as described here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subdomain_delegation_guide.htm&type=5), you will be able to use RMM for sure.